# how to represent xml as a tree

Tags: xml

how to represent xml as an a tree is there any available tool

Answer (score 0):

XML is by design already a hierarchical tree of nodes.

How do you want it represented? What programming language are you using? What kind of tool?

Comment: i want it as a schemas hirarchical

Comment: What is a "schemas hirarchical"? Can you link to a definition?

Comment: http://www.dit.unitn.it/~p2p/matching/SWAP06-OMtutorial.pdf

i want it to appeare as in slide 6

Comment: I don't know of any tool that will do that automatically. You can write something yourself with some graphics libraries.

Comment: How would you treat attributes and the different kinds of nodes? E.g. there are elements, comments, processing-instructions and text nodes…